# How to create internationalized static pages in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization

I have a project (symfony 2.3) and I have some static pages, but i need i18n. What is the best way to achieve it?

I was trying something like this with specific twig templates for each locale, but not work.

```
static_about:
path: /{_locale}/about
defaults:
    _controller:  FrameworkBundle:Template:template
    template:     'EscFrontendBundle:Static/{_locale}_about.html.twig'
```

Answer (score 2):

**problem:**

While `{_locale}` in the `path` works with static content ...

... `{_locale}` in the route's `template` setting is not being replaced by symfony.

---

**solution:**

To overcome this just use a "base" twig template `about.html.twig` containing an include like this:

```
{% include app.request.locale ~ '_about.html.twig' %}
```